# Auto Size TextView for TextSwitcher

Tags: java, android, textview, android-8.0-oreo

I see that Android released in `Oreo` a new attribute for `textView`:

```
android:autoSizeTextType
```

This adapts the layout of the `textView` based on the string of text that it is showing.

How would I be able to use this with a `textSwitcher`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello" />

 private ViewFactory viewFactory = new ViewFactory() {
    public View makeView()  {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(TextSwitcherTest.this);
        TextView textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.textView, null);
        return textView;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the ones above but here's an solution with minimal coding. You can change the main layout height to see the autosizing in action, or you can tap the upper switcher. A cool feature is that the styling of the second text field carries over when tapped (i.e. text is white).

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun switchText(v: View) {
        (v as? TextSwitcher)?.let{
            it.tag = (((it.tag as? Int) ?: 0) + 1) % it.childCount
            it.setText((it.children.toList()[it.tag as Int] as TextView).text)
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/b"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        android:onClick="switchText"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="999 / 999"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.05"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="936sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="28sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:lines="1"
            android:includeFontPadding="false" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/a2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="1000000 / 10000000"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.05"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="136sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="28sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:lines="1"
            android:includeFontPadding="false" />
    </TextSwitcher>
    <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="999 / 999"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.05"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="136sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="28sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:lines="1"
            android:includeFontPadding="false" />

    </TextSwitcher>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    altitudeSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.altitude);
    altitudeSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {

        @Override
        public View makeView() {


            TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50);

            return t;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand how that textView will adapt to the text inside it?

Comment: @Isaac In Android, TextSwitcher is a specialised ViewSwitcher that contains only children of type TextView.
- setFactory method is used to create a new view for TextSwitcher. By using this method we create a new TextView and replace the old view with that.

Comment: It's probably easier to inflate a textView than to create it in code, but I get the idea.

Comment: @Isaac Yes you can check out the new answer for that